# How to write a PDF with better Copy-Paste for text?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am writing some code to generate PDFs, and am frustrated by the fact that the text positioning and text showing operators cause Acrobat to insert newlines into any text copied from the resulting document.

I've tried different combinations of the text showing operators: `Td`, `Td` with manually set `TL` (test leading), using `Tm` to change the text matrix directly, `TJ` for more detailed text positioning, and even adding spaces at the end of the first line, in case that made Acrobat reconsider. But all of them produce the same behaviour, where the text is copied to the clipboard in acrobat as `"Hello world\nTesting"`.

```
BT
/F0 24 Tf
24 TL % Directly set text leading
200 500 Td
(Hello world) Tj
(Testing) '
ET

BT
1 0 0 1 200 300 Tm
(Hello world) Tj
1 0 0 1 200 276 Tm % Manually reset text matrix
(Testing) Tj
ET

BT
1 0 0 1 200 200 Tm
[ (Hello world) ] TJ % Use more specific text positioning operator
1 0 0 1 200 176 Tm
[ (Testing) ] TJ
ET
```

I tried using `/Span` to create a marked content sequence, but this also did not have the desired effect.

```
% Attempt at using a marked content sequence
/Span <</MCID 0>> BDC
BT
1 0 0 1 200 200 Tm
[ (Hello world) ] TJ
1 0 0 1 200 176 Tm
[ (Testing) ] TJ
ET
EMC
```

It seems that marked content sequences are probably the way to go here, but I'm unsure what version of this system to use. It seems unreasonable that I would need to go all the way to a Tagged PDF just to have Acrobat understand that a change in the text matrix doesn't necessarily indicate the presence of a newline. Is there some trick with the alternative text feature?

So, the question is: Am I missing a simple trick, or does this require something along the lines of a full Tagged PDF just to be able to delineate paragraphs?

Comment: There is a change in the **y** coordinate between "Hello World" and "Testing" in all your cases. No matter how this is achieved, this is generally interpreted as a NewLine by text extractors. The only way to prevent this in some extractors would be to use an **ActualText** marked content property.

Comment: That is certainly an option. However, as an example, the PDF 2.0 specification PDF has the behaviour I'm looking for, and seems to achieve it without using ActualText markers. What I'm seeing in the page content streams is something like `/Span <</MCID 5 /Lang (en-US)>> BDC ... EMC` with multiple text objects inside the marked content sequence. However, this is a massive document, and I can't work out what additional data is being used to create the behaviour. If I extract a page with qpdf or GhostScript, the text copies with newlines again.